# theano compile to source code

Tags: theano, symbolic-math

Is there method to compile the theano function into a C (or C++) source code so that I can modify it and port it to other platform?

I have a look in ~/.theano. The content there is not really helpful. 
The directory consists of a lot of tmpXXXX sub-directories and mod.cpp. They are not really readable.

Basically I just need **symbolic differentiation** and output the result as C source code. If theano does not help, are there any other framework / libraries that could do the job?

Comment: No, you can't, not easily at least. Theano-generated C++ code for a Theano function is truly ugly, given that it supports hundreds of different Ops, calls a variety of external C & C++ libraries, and has to perform perfect error management for all of them to avoid corrupting or crashing the Python runtime above. The code that Theano generates isn't standalone; It depends on all of those libraries plus the Python runtime. If you want something standalone you're gonna have to look elsewhere.